# Veracode CWE 501 Flaw Trust Boundary Violation In JSP File

Tags: java, jsp, veracode

I am getting veracode flaw cwe id 501 on the line like session.setAttribute(var1,var2). I have already tried different ways to resolve it but unable to fix this issue. The ways which I have tried are following-
1. I have used a String literal and passed var1 into it. Finally I have used that String in that vulnerable line.
2. As per the suggestion given in the different blogs I have tried regex for input validation like pattern.matches("[0-9A-Fa-f]+").
3. I have also used ESAPI for input validation.
4. Moreover, I have checked the value of var1 and only if it is null I have set value to var2 into var1.

After trying all the above mentioned scenarios I am still getting 501 trust boundary violation issue in veracode. Can anybody please help me on that? Is there any other way to make fool veracode static scan for this issue? Please reply. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Error description in veracode-

This call to javax.servlet.http.HttpSession.setAttribute() mixes trusted and untrusted data in the same data structure, thereby encouraging programmers to mistakenly trust unvalidated data. The first argument to setAttribute() contains tainted data from the variable PDTYPE. The tainted data originated from an earlier call to javax.servlet.ServletRequest.getParameterNames.